# Adding an NSView at top left and filling window

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am programmatically adding an `NSView` to an `NSWindow`. I want to have the new view appear at the top left and fill the entire window.

I have been messing around with autolayout and manually setting frames and autoresizing masks (not at the same time, obviously), but I'm getting nowhere. Either the view doesn't resize at all, or it resizes proportionally (using autoresizing masks) but it won't fill the entire space. I must be missing something basic.

I am new to Mac Cocoa, although I'm quite experienced at iOS Cocoa Touch. On iOS, CGPoint 0,0 is top left. I assume on Mac from what I'm seeing that it's bottom left. How do you figure out what top left is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the autoresizing mask like below should do the trick:

```
view.autoresizingMask = NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable
```

Absence of other resizing masks makes the margins inflexible. So whatever is the current margin (which is zero on all sides, when you add it to the window - Assuming the view occupies the full window frame when being added) is retained.

And top left would be the window's content view's height.

```
[[self.window.contentView frame].size.height]
```

I guess you already knew that. :)

Comment: That helped. The final piece of the puzzle was setting the table's frame to the window contentview's bounds. Thanks.